# `R` equivalent to pythons `from src.file import function, class, variable`?

Tags: r, oop, import, r-package, modularity

I have defined three different S4 classes in their own scripts in my R package. One of those classes uses the other two classes.

I see that `devtools::load_all()` loads the scripts in alphabetical order, so that if a script depends on another that is later in alphabetical order, there may be problems. Observe:

*Example script `a.r`:*

```
setClass("a", slots = c(name = "character"))
```

*Example script `b.r`*

```
setClass("b", slots = c(name = "character", a = "a", c = "c"))
```

*Example script `c.r`:*

```
setClass("c", slots = c(name = "character"))
```

When I run `devtools::load_all()`, the following warning appears:

```
Warning messages:
1: undefined slot classes in definition of "b": c(class "c")
```

I do not want to rename my scripts simply to put them in alphabetical order based on when I want them to be loaded.

I do not want to define those classes in a single script, because I want to keep the code more modular.

**How do I ensure that the script defining the dependent class has access to the other classes:**

1. Regardless of the names of the scripts those classes are in?
2. Without resorting to `source()` since this would import other functions, objects, variables, from that script that are not needed.

---

In `python`, this is relatively trivial. One uses a syntax like:

`from <relative path to .py file that defines those objects> import <desired objects>`

In `R`, I am spinning in circles trying to accomplish something similar.

Comment: It is only a warning. Unless your scripts instantiate the classes, you can create them even if they have references to unloaded classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable solution by digging into the `Collate` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

When I append this to the `DESCRIPTION` file, then the warning goes away when I run `devtools::load_all()` because files will be loaded in the order I specified rather than alphabetical order:

```
Collate:
    a.r
    c.r
    b.r
```

This does not answer the more general question about how to replicate the behavior of `python` by only importing specific objects defined in another script... The `load_all()` functionality still seems to load everything in the scripts, and the `Collate` section simply specifies the order... But I'll still count this as a win.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as your  `b.r` macro would like to have `class(c)` defined,  I strongly recommend you explicitly include the command  `load(c.r)`  at the top of the `b.r` macro.  Otherwise when someone tries to set up something with `load(b.r)`  rather than "load.all()`  there'll be a failure anyway.    Always avoid depending on the user executing something "extra" .

Comment: Isn't `load()` meant for loading RData files first saved with `save()`?

Adding `load(c.r)` to the top of `b.r` leads to a different error when then trying `load_all()`: `object c.r not found`.

If you meant to suggest I should add `source("R/c.r")` to the top of `b.r`, then that is something I am explicitly trying to avoid since I only want to import the definition of the class defined in `c.r`, not everything else that may be defined in that script.

Comment: @Jayden.Cameron  ok,  yes,  so use `source()` .    But if you're going to be that specific with imports, then create a `thing.r` script for each class you want to define and have your `c.r` script invoke the class defintion script